# Get data of custom table error in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to get data of the custom table, this is my code

```
$address = Mage::getModel ( 'shippingaddresses/shippingaddresses' )->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter(
                   array(
                             array("account_id",["eq"=>$customerNumber]),
                             array("account_name",["like"=>"%".$customerName."%"]),
                             array("shipping_city",["like"=>"%".$customerCity."%"]),
                             array("shipping_postal_code",["like"=>"%".$customerCode."%"])
                   )
        );
```

My error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'account_id.Array' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `commercers_shippingaddresses` AS `main_table` WHERE ((`account_id`.`Array` = '') OR (`account_name`.`Array` = '') OR (`shipping_city`.`Array` = '') OR (`shipping_postal_code`.`Array` = ''))";i:1;s:2143:
```

UPDATE

I tryed this code but this has a problem. I need it find AND.

```
$address = Mage::getModel ( 'shippingaddresses/shippingaddresses' )
                  ->getCollection()
                  ->addFieldToFilter(['account_id', 'account_name', 'shipping_city', 'shipping_postal_code'],
                   [
                       ['eq' => $customerNumber],
                       ['like' => "%".$customerName."%"],
                       ['like' => "%".$customerCity."%"],
                       ['eq' => $customerCode]

                   ]);
```

Comment: Please check$customerNumber getting in array.

Comment: Is this your custom table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$address = Mage::getModel('shippingaddresses/shippingaddresses')->getCollection();

$address->getSelect()->where("account_id = $customerNumber and account_name like '%$customerName%' and shipping_city like '%$customerCity%' and shipping_postal_code like '%$customerCode%'");
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it work for me <3 have a nice day Sweety Masmiya

Comment: Thank you :-) Happy codding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$address = Mage::getModel('shippingaddresses/shippingaddresses')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('account_id', ['eq' => $customerNumber])
            ->addFieldToFilter('account_name', ['like'=> '%' . $customerName . '%'])
            ->addFieldToFilter('shipping_city', ['like'=> '%' . $customerCity . '%'])
            ->addFieldToFilter('shipping_postal_code', ['like'=> '%' . $customerCode . '%']);
```

Comment: anh check lại câu hỏi giúp em với, hình như nó search bằng OR

Comment: Mình update lại câu tra lời rồi bạn nhé.

Comment: Code mới chạy ko bạn?

Comment: dạ không đúng ý em anh ơi, nhưng mà code của bạn đẹp Sweety Masmiya ổn rồi anh ơi, thanks anh nhé <3

Comment: Ukm. hihi. Lạ nhỉ?

Comment: dùng nó là em phải search hết field 1 lần ấy, còn search từng cái nó không load ra được :D

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code to try with array

```
$address = Mage::getModel('shippingaddresses/shippingaddresses') ->getCollection() ->addFieldToSelect('*') ->addFieldToFilter( array('account_id', 'account_name', 'shipping_city', 'shipping_postal_code'), array( array('eq' => $customerNumber), array('like'=> '%' . $customerName . '%'), array('like'=> '%' . $customerCity . '%'), array('like'=> '%' . $customerCode . '%') ) );
```

Comment: please check update question